# Why does std::istream::getline not operate on std::string?

Tags: c++, istream

In C++, `istream` has a method called `getline` which operate on a C-style character array. I know there are other independent `getline` functions which operate on an `istream` and a `std::string`. But why a separate method? Why not put it in `istream`? And why does `istream`'s getline only work on C-style strings instead of `std::string`?

Answer (score 2):

I think the *strings* library and the *streams* library were developed separately. I think that is why we don't have universal `std::string` support in the *streams* library. Although that has been addressed a little but with `std::fstream::open` now taking *strings*.

One thing to note is that `std::istream::getline` is more secure than `std::getline` so should be preferred in some situations.

The problem is `std::getline` has no checking on the length of string that will be read. That means malicious code (or a corrupt data source) can blow the memory by presenting data containing a very long line.

With `std::istream::getline` you have a limit on how much can be read.

Answer (score 1):

My thought is that it is designed for performance reason. You can allocate a block of buffer just once, and could iteratively process line-by-line. Note that `std::getline` which takes `std::string` as argument, calls `s.erase()` before writing to `s` and it may cause `s` to allocate more buffer if the line is too long.